# get Common Documents folder in VBS

Tags: windows, vbscript, installation, installshield, special-folders

To my great chagrin, I must use VBS to write an InstallShield 2010 LE custom action.  I have no VBS experience so I'm basically putting together code snippets that I find.

I need to get a hold of the Common Documents folder (CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS).  It's not defined in `WScript.Shell.SpecialFolders` (although All Users Desktop is).  I found some example code that tries to link to a system DLL:

```
Private Declare Function SHGetFolderPath Lib "shfolder.dll" _
Alias "SHGetFolderPathA" _
    (ByVal hwndOwner As Long, _
    ByVal nFolder As Long, _
    ByVal hToken As Long, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
    ByVal lpszPath As String) As Long
```

But when I try to run it in VbsEdit, I get the following error on the first line:

`Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement`

Any ideas?

Comment: Easier to pass it in as a paraneter from installshield usually. That way you can control where you are doing what from one place.

Comment: Installshield help says: "VBScript functions cannot take arguments from custom actions."  How would I do it?

Comment: Um didn't know that, but youy can cheat and use Session.Property. So you set a property docFolder outside the script then pick it up inside the function and use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stolen from [here](http://spablog.ontrex.ch/2010/03/11/zusatzliche-special-folders/)

```
  Const CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS = &h2e
  Dim objShell : Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  WScript.Echo objShell.Namespace(CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS).Self.Path
```

output:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents
```

Comment: Technically this code won't work in a custom action because there isn't a WScript object available while running as an MSI CA. The default object is the Session object not WScript or CScript.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that VBScript custom actions are very problematic, you can just ask WindowsInstaller for the location of the CommonAppDataFolder.

[CommonAppDataFolder Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367992%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

```
commonAppDataFolder = session.Property("CommonAppDataFolder")
```

Comment: What makes them so problematic?  I am already annoyed at working with VBS, I'd like some good reasons to switch!

Comment: Read the link below for reasons.   As to alternative,s I have some great content on my blog discussing how to write clean managed code custom actions using WiX DTF, encapsulate them into WiX merge modules and consoume then in InstallShield LE projects.  IS LE is very limited in what in where it lets you schedule CA's and my solution works around all of that to get the full power of MSI.http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2004/05/20/136530.aspx