# Error 91 using CreateObject on XP machines

Tags: vb6, special-folders, createobject

I have an old VB6 app that I've distributed to several users running XP, Windows 7 and Windows 8.  The following code is throwing an Error 91 ""Object variable or With block variable not set".

```
Const ssfPERSONAL = 46  'set directory to the common Documents folder
Dim strMyDocsPath As String  'stores common docsPath
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

strMyDocsPath = CreateObject("Shell.Application").NameSpace(ssfPERSONAL).Self.Path
```

Specifically, the last line is the issue. I want strMyDocsPath to point to the common documents folder on the user machine.  It works fine in Windows 7 and 8, but not on XP machines except the XP development machine where it runs without a hitch.

On the problem computers, I have tried re-registering scrrrun.dll and got a message it registered successfully.  I tried downloading and installing the VB6 distributable SP6 files and still get the error. I have searched several forums and just can't figure it out.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try using an intermediate variable to create the object, using the `Set` keyword. Then assign the string to the string variable.

Comment: The Shell is Windows Explorer, it has nothing to do with the Scripting Runtime.

Answer (score 3):

It is usually useful to un-lump complex one-liners in one call per line fashion when debugging such kind of an error:

```
Dim DebugObj1 As Object
Dim DebugObj2 As Object
Dim DebugObj3 As Object

Set DebugObj1 = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Debug.Print "1: " & CStr(DebugObj1 Is Nothing)
Set DebugObj2 = DebugObj1.NameSpace(ssfPERSONAL)
Debug.Print "2: " & CStr(DebugObj2 Is Nothing)
Set DebugObj3 = DebugObj2.Self
Debug.Print "3: " & CStr(DebugObj3 Is Nothing)
strMyDocsPath = DebugObj3.Path

Debug.Print strMyDocsPath
```

After that it is easier to spot what call doesn't return useful object, exactly. In your case it is most likely `.NameSpace(ssfPERSONAL)`.

I was able to reproduce your problem in Windows XP SP3 if Shared Documents are disabled. There are many ways to disable them. See this, for example: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/how-to-remove-shared-documents-icon-from-my-computer-in-windows-xp/

As a side note, `ShellSpecialFolderConstants.ssfPersonal` is actually `0x05`, see [MSDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731534/get-common-documents-folder-in-vbs). The value `46` (or `0x2e`) you use is `CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS` which indeed translates to Common Documents folder like `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents`. Probably, it is not the very best practice to use misleading naming.

Comment: This is exactly why such a location is not meant for unattended use by a program, i.e. unless the user is allowed to navigate there via Save dialogs and such.

Comment: You are correct in that .namespace(ssfPERSONAL) returned nothing.  However, the shared documents are completely visible on the machine and the folder settings appear identical on my XP machine which works perfect.  There machine is on a network, mine isn't - could that be the issue?  Could the folder still be disabled even though I see it?  If so, how do I enable?  I guess another question that would help solve my problem is this:  Is there another way I can  use code to determine the users "common documents" folder?

Comment: @JohnMarzion So you're able to access the folder using Windows Explorer application? Interesting. To find out why your application fails I'd do this: download Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx); set filter "Process Name" = "YourApp.exe"; monitor registry and file system activity. In my case, the last activity before VB error is a read of this registry path: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoSharedDocuments.

Comment: @kurniliya: I did what you suggested (thanks for the idea) and I'm getting "Access Denied" error when it tried to access the users local settings folder.  It's not the common documents folder, but a temp folder under the specific user/local settings/temp/.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @JohnMarzion I'm guessing that's because that location **is** the folder which shell considers `CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS`. And you do not have access writes for it. To be sure, check the registy. If memory serves me well, location goes like this `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\`. Try accessing said folder via Windows Explorer -- I bet you'll not be able to.